# I want to run the screenshot function via asynchronous communication

Tags: php, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, asynchronous, async-await

I would like to create a site that outputs a screenshot of the URL destination and the expiration date of the ssl certificate when the URL is entered. The screenshots are done using selenium. However, screenshots using selenium take a bit of time, so I would like to display the site results without waiting for the screenshot results, and output the screenshot as soon as it is taken.

selenium_function.py

```
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os 
import re
import sys


if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("argument isnt two")

else:
    url = sys.argv[1]
    
    #headless
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
    options.add_argument('--incognito')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)

    driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds

    driver.get(url)

    sanitizedurl = re.sub(r'[\\/:*?"<>|]+','',url)

    driver.get_screenshot_as_file(os.getcwd() + "\\ss\\" + sanitizedurl + "_small" + "_screenshot" + ".png")

    width = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollWidth;")
    height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
    driver.set_window_size(width,height)

    driver.get_screenshot_as_file(os.getcwd() + "\\ss\\" + sanitizedurl + "_big" + "_screenshot" + ".png")

    print(sanitizedurl)
```

test.php

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $url = urldecode($url);
    $pythonScript = "selenium_function.py";

    $command = "C:/Users/~~~~~~~/Python311/python.exe $pythonScript $url";
    $output = exec($command);

    $output_sanitizedurl = mb_convert_encoding($output, "UTF-8", "auto");

    $date = "2024/01/01";
}
?>

<head>
    <title>URL_SCREENSHOT</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>URL_SCREENSHOT</h1>

    <form method="post" action="test.php">
        <label for="url">Input URL:</label>
        <input type="text" name="url" id="url" required>
        <input type="submit" value="take a screenshot">
    </form>
    <h2>SSL_DATE</h2>
    <?php if(isset($date)){echo $date;}?>
    <h3>Screenshot</h3>
        <a href="./ss/<?php echo $output_sanitizedurl?>_big_screenshot.png" target="_blank" >
            <img src="./ss/<?php echo $output_sanitizedurl?>_small_screenshot.png" width="100%">
        </a>
</body>
</html>
```

I have been trying to do asynchronous processing and have looked into async/await and tried it, but it did not work as expected. I am also wondering if asynchronous processing is the right solution for what I am trying to do now.
Please help.

Comment: Asynchrony should be on php/JS, if you do `$command = "C:/Users/~~~~~~~/Python311/python.exe $pythonScript $url"; $output = exec($command);` in the page that shows the result of course it'll wait for the result to exist before showing the page.

Comment: You should rethink how to build this page of yours, show the page, then with JS you call an API to get the screenshot, show a spinner so the user knows it's loading or save a job id somewhere so the user can come back and check if it's finished

Comment: I don't believe you can make asynchronous requests to the wire protocol (that's the driver to the browser and vice-versa).   Your take screenshot call will wait for a promise to return from the browser (the screenshot).